# How to SSH between two servers behind firewalls (without a 3rd party server)

Tags: ssh, firewall, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

There are many posts on this topic and SSH Tunnelling however, some come close to meeting this requirement, missing out a step or two and others are difficult to follow because of unclear terms. This is an attempt to provide a framework, in which ambiguity of steps is removed.

**Problem**: We have a Server (RPC-2) that sits inside a Remote Network behind a Remote Router (RR) connected to the Internet. Our Local PC LCP-1 on the network is behind a Local Router (LR). We have access to port forwarding settings on the LR.

We can run commands on both LCP-1 and RPC-2 and change settings on the LR. What are the steps to enable an SSH to start from RPC-2 and connect to SSH on LPC-1?

[image]

```
Here is what I believe the steps to be run in this order:
    1.  RPC-2> ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 42.48.128.49
    2.  On LR> Port forward 12345 to 192.168.1.16 port 12345
    3.  LPC-1> ssh -p 12345 localhost
```

This has not worked for us yet. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In order to allow an SSH connection from RPC-2 to LPC-1 you need to set up port forwarding on LR from an arbitrary port on the outside to the SSH port of LPC-1.
You can then connect with SSH from RPC-2 to that port and you'll reach LPC-1.
So:

**1.** On LR> Port forward 12345 to 192.168.1.16 port **22**

**2.** RPC-2> ssh **-p 12345** 42.48.128.49

If you want to allow SSH connections in the *opposite* direction (from LPC-1 to RPC-2), as your proposed steps seem to suggest, you can tunnel them through that first SSH connection.
So:

**1.** On LR> Port forward 12345 to 192.168.1.16 port **22**

**2.** RPC-2> ssh **-p 12345** -R **54321**:localhost:22 42.48.128.49

**3.** LPC-1> ssh -p **54321** localhost

Note: I changed one of your two port numbers from 12345 to 54321 to make it clear that the two are independent separate ports.

Comment: Sorry for piggybacking an old question, but I'm trying to get the exact second scenario (from LPC-1 to RPC-2) working and when I execute step #3, I am prompted with a password challenge that actually just SSH's me into LPC-1.. from LPC-1. Any idea how I might have flubbed this? 

I've definitely confirmed the tunnel exists and is listening from RPC-2.

Comment: I would have to see your exact configuration otherwise I can but speculate.

Comment: If the userids are different, when ssh'ing from LPC1 via tunnel to RPC2, you need to specify the userid _on RPC2_. See @SIRCAVEC's followup https://superuser.com/questions/1749280/ssh-reverse-tunneling-to-a-linux-machine/1749291#1749291 .