# SSH reverse tunneling to a linux machine

Tags: networking, ssh, nat, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I have essentially the same configuration as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1698908/how-to-ssh-between-two-servers-behind-firewalls-without-a-3rd-party-server/1698931#1698931?newreg=ac7b8edfed54478f8c9663b75e018b36) (relevant image below):

[image]

where I want to be able to ssh into `RPC-2` from either `LPC-1` directly and from any arbitrary machine via `LPC-1`. I have control over the router `LR` but not `RR`, and of course full control over both machines.

I have followed the steps in the answer provided for the original question, that is:

1. On LR> Port forward 22222 to 192.168.1.16 port 22
2. RPC-2> `ssh -f -N -T -p22222 -R8022:localhost:22 42.48.128.49`
3. LPC-1> `ssh -p8022 localhost`

However, when I run step #3, it doesn't appear as if the traffic is being properly forwarded to `RPC-2` because the password challenge that comes up is in fact for the system on `LPC-1` (the only credentials that worked were for `userLPC1`). I end up ssh-ing into `LPC-1` from `LPC-1` !

Any ideas or suggestions on how to set this up properly are appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSH tunnel is correct, but when you run `ssh` on LPC1 *as userLPC1* without specifying a userid, it connects to RPC2 over the tunnel but **logs-in as userLPC1** i.e. the same userid as the system where you ran `ssh`.

Specify the correct userid like `ssh -p8022 userRPC2@localhost`.

Or possibly better, in `.ssh/config` put something like

```
Host tunneltoRPC2
  Hostname localhost
  Port 8022
  User userRPC2 # optional
```

so you can say `ssh tunneltoRPC2` (or `userRPC2@tunneltoRPC2` if you omit `User`) and it will actually connect to/via localhost 8022.

---

Added: on first pass I missed the 'arbitrary machines' until you reminded me, and clarified (some). That gets more complicated, especially for things *other than* SSH like your browser. Taking it in steps:

For other machines in LAN1 (besides LPC1) to similarly make SSH connections to RPC2, you must:

1. change the initial setup on LPC2 to `-R*:8022:localhost:22` which tells sshd in LPC1 to listen (for this tunnel) on all interfaces rather than only loopback. You *can* instead use a specific bind address like `-R192.168.1.16:8022:localhost:22` but in this simple setup there's no reason to.
2. have `GatewayPorts on` in (usually) `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in LPC1. This is usually not the default so you need to change it and restart sshd (possibly by rebooting).

To allow SSH from machines outside your LAN *additionally*:

3. set LR to forward some suitable port on 42.48.128.49 to  192.168.1.16 8022
4. outside machines then do `ssh userRPC2@42.48.128.49 -pthatport` (or use `.ssh/config` equivalent)

For other *applications*, possibly such as web browsing, there are several alternatives:

5. add another `-R` e.g. if for HTTP you want to forward 80 on LPC1 to 80 on LPC2 `-R[:]80:localhost:80`. Then have programs on LPC1, other LAN1 machines, or outside make requests on/via LPC1 per the rules above. (But see note below about HTTP.)
   This means you need to restart your 'foundation' SSH from RPC2 to LPC1 (breaking any in-progress operations) if/when the set of ports changes -- unless you use the 'ControlMaster' functionality of recent OpenSSH, which becomes even more complicated -- so you probably want this only if the set of ports is static or nearly so.

5A: (leave the foundation the same and) on LPC1 run `ssh -N userRPC2@localhost -L80:localhost:80` and now if programs on LPC1 connect to either localhost:80 or 192.168.1.16:80 they will actually get RPC2:80. Machines elsewhere on LAN1 must use the latter, and machines outside must use 42.48.128.49:someport which is forwarded to that.

5B: if the client applications are SOCKS-capable, (leave foundation and) on LPC1 run `ssh -N userRPC2@localhost -Dsomeport` then have the program on LPC1 use localhost:someport *as a SOCKS proxy* while connecting to localhost:80, or somename:80 where somename resolves to 127.0.0.1, either of which will actually be RPC2:80. Elsewhere in LAN1 use 192.168.1.16:someport as the proxy (but still specify the target as localhost or something that resolves to 127.0.0.1) and outside use 42.48.128.49:routerport which is forwarded to 192.168.1.16:someport (ditto).

However for some applications *particularly* the web (HTTP/S) this may not work. For many traditional network applications it's enough to get a connection to the correct address and port, even going via a different-looking address or name and port as here. But for HTTP/1.1 up it is often necessary to connect using the 'real' name of the server (i.e. RPC2 or some variant or alias) because this is used in the HTTP protocol to select/deliver the correct content, and for all versions of HTTPS it is usually necessary because the server's certificate contains its predefined name or names, and if the name requested by the browser/client does not match a name in the certificate the connection fails. Thus you may need to:

6. set up name resolution used by the client machine(s) or program(s) -- LPC1, elsewhere on LAN1, or outside -- so they lookup the real name ('RPC2' or whatever) but get the addresses specified above such as 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.16 or 42.48.128.49 as applicable. But in LAN2 you must keep the 'real' name resolution of RPC2 to its real address 192.168.2.72. This can be done fairly simply with the /etc/hosts file if you have only one or a few machine(s) and no or infrequent changes; otherwise you probably need some kind(s) of 'split' or 'localized' or outright faked DNS. This can get *very* complicated and there isn't an 'arbitrary' solution; you need to specify details, and maybe implement several different solutions for different sets of details.

So if you've reached this point you might want to consider:

7. INSTEAD USE A VPN. Unlike SSH tunnelling, VPN is a technology designed to actually implement networking between 'isolated' subnets so that network protocols and applications work normally without alteration.

Comment: Thank you!! The usage of `localhost` in this scenario is still confusing at times..

Comment: I only mentioned it in passing in the original question, but I am also trying to use LPC1 as a bridge for any machine outside of that local network. So far I am able to ssh into LPC1 and ssh again into RPC2, however I would also like to access other ports/services on RPC2 on my laptop's web browser. If I'm understanding the concepts properly, I should be able to set up tunnels to do this as well?


EDIT: It works!

Comment: Sorry if I'm not supposed to ask follow ups in comments! I'm not sure what the etiquette is for this site.

Comment: SIRCAVEC: it varies. Minor clarifications are fine, especially as here where it actually was in the Q and I missed it; see 'added' section. Significant changes or additions should be editted into the Q (although you might also comment to call an answerer's attention to the change) because _other people_ who find this by searching or browsing will start reading with the Q at the top. Something that is actually a different question, even if related, should go in a new Q, with a link to the prior one if that context is relevant.